# Reference Thread Saftey

Tags: c#

I quickly wrote this in notepad, I apologize if there are errors.

I have two classes Alpha and Beta. Alpha only exposes thread safe operations. Beta accesses these operations on another thread. Is this thread safe?

Is passing the reference of Alpha to Beta thread safe?

Example:

```
public class Alpha
{
    readonly private object key = new object();
    private int _notThreadSafe = 0;
    public int ThreadSafeProperty
    {
        set
        {
            lock(key)
            {
                _notThreadSafe = value;
            }
        }
        get
        {
            int temp;
            lock(key)
            {
                temp = _notThreadSafe;
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public Alpha()
    {
        Thread ClientThread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            new Beta(this);
        });
        ClientThread.Start();
    }

    public class Beta
    {
        public Beta(Alpha ParentClass)
        {
            if(ParentClass != null)
            {
                ParentClass.ThreadSafeProperty = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if `A` is supposed to be thread-safe, that means that it can be accessed by another thread, safely. So you're question is what happens when you access thread-safe code from another thread? It's accessed, safedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reads and writes to `ThreadSafeProperty` will be atomic, if that's what you need for thread-safety, yes. If your real-life usage is as simple as this, I would recommending replacing the `lock` with `Interlocked.Exchange()`.

Comment: What about checking the null on ParentClass? Is that a Thread Safe?

Comment: @NathanSurfus No other thread could modify nor be effected by the modification of the local variable `ParentClass` (Note, I am taking about the variable itself, not the object the variable is pointing to), so yes it is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You appear to be a bit confused about when things can change "under the covers".

1. ParentClass is a local variable that is passed by the thread initializer and then does not change. It (ParentClass) holds a reference to Alpha, which is thread safe. Therefore the accesses to ParentClass are safe.
2. As written, the lock statements do not buy you any additional safety. In .net variable setters such as _notThreadSafe = value are guaranteed to be atomic, i.e. if the integer is 4 bytes long there is no chance of reading it such that e.g. 2 bytes are from the old value and 2 bytes are from the new value. Therefore, unless your getters/setters get more complicated, you can get rid of the locks, and just write:

   ```
   public int ThreadSafeProperty { get; set; }
   ```